# How can you redownload something with rTorrent?

Tags: rtorrent

Let's say I'm using rTorrent and I accidentally delete the underlying file. But the torrent still shows in the rTorrent download list, is there a method to re-download the same thing?

Or.. better, since rTorrent still has an open file handle to move it back to the location?

Answer (score 0):

Use,

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to stop
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to reset
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to start

That sequence seems to work.